# Tomcat 7 manager app not prompt for login

Tags: tomcat

When I first go to the manager app `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`, there was a browser prompt login window asking for username and password. By entering the wrong username and password, the page returned 403(access denied).

So I googled a bit and setup as follows:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<user username="admin" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
<!-- these 2 lines was there before my editing -->
<user password="tom" roles="manager-script,admin" username="tom"/>
<user password="tomcat" roles="manager-script,admin" username="tomcat"/>
```

After restarting tomcat, the manager app this time shows 403 page directly without asking for username and password.
So I'm a bit confused. What kind of authentication is this manager app using?
And how can I login to the manager app?

Comment: Tomcat manager uses basic authentication. Username and password must match the user in tomcat-users.xml with the role manager-gui. Have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the browser and its policy to preserve active logins. For Firefox you can go to ''Tools'' -> ''Clear Recent History...'' and clear ''Active Logins''. Refreshing your manager app after that will pop up the prompt you were asking for.

Cheers,
β

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem, I found that the following fragment **must** be present in WEB-INF/web.xml to let the browser prompt for a username and password.

```html
<!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
<login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Tomcat Host Manager Application</realm-name>
</login-config>
```